# sstableloader connection refused, though can be connected via cqlsh

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to connect to the remote server but get the following exception....
Somehow, it seems that the cassandra fails to connect to each node...

```
user$ sstableloader -d 192.168.33.11  /usr/local/var/lib/cassandra/data/moomin/hoahoa2/
Streaming revelant part of /usr/local/var/lib/cassandra/data/moomin/hoahoa2/moomin-hoahoa2-hf-37-Data.db /usr/local/var/lib/cassandra/data/moomin/hoahoa2/moomin-hoahoa2-hf-62-Data.db /usr/local/var/lib/cassandra/data/moomin/hoahoa2/moomin-hoahoa2-hf-63-Data.db to [/192.168.33.12, /192.168.33.11]

progress: [/192.168.33.12 0/3 (0)] [/192.168.33.11 0/3 (0)] [total: 0 - 0MB/s (avg: 0MB/s)] WARN 13:57:59,232 Failed attempt 1 to connect to /192.168.33.12 to stream /usr/local/var/lib/cassandra/data/moomin/hoahoa2/moomin-hoahoa2-hf-63-Data.db sections=1 progress=0/302778 - 0%. Retrying in 4000 ms. (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused)
 WARN 13:57:59,232 Failed attempt 1 to connect to /192.168.33.11 to stream /usr/local/var/lib/cassandra/data/moomin/hoahoa2/moomin-hoahoa2-hf-63-Data.db sections=1 progress=0/294966 - 0%. Retrying in 4000 ms. (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused)
progress: [/192.168.33.12 0/3 (0)] [/192.168.33.11 0/3 (0)] [total: 0 - 0MB/
```

[1] via cqlsh, I can connect to either nodes smoothly.

[2] the cassandra.yaml file in each node has rpc_address: 0.0.0.0

Can anyone give me advice?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally got it, the cassandra version of each nodes are not identical, do it caused the `java.net.ConnectionException` Error. So all I gotta do was make sure that cassandra version of each node identical.

if cassandra version is the same, the java version do not have to be the same.